# Excel with 4,000,000 rows

Tags: excel, pivot-table, powerquery, powerpivot

I would like to consolidate 4 files which contain approximately 800,000 rows each, into one single file.
The reason I need this is that I have to create a pivot which reads the data from all these 4 files.
Is there a way to do this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think using power query to consolidate (and maybe trim?) the tables might be an option, but with this amount of data I would start thinking about whether using Excel is my best option.

Comment: You should consider using powerpivot, or even better Power BI.

Comment: @mxix Why Power BI? That is good for data visualisations, but Excel Power Pivot is far superior when it comes to pivot tables. Never mind the ease of use, familiarity with the environment and no additional cost for sharing the file with other users. Power BI is good for browser based reporting with nice charts, but it's not necessarily the best tool for all data purposes.

Comment: @teylyn All true, except for sharing costs. You don't have to pay anything to share a file. I guess"even better" was a poor choice of words, more of an alternative if you want the extra capabilities of power bi versus the less powerfull pivoting options.

Comment: You can send people the PBIX file, yes. But sharing a report in the browser requires more than the free license. Editing in PBI Desktop is quite different from consuming a report in the browser and creating a dashboard, and not everybody consuming a report will know what to do with a PBIX file. Or have PBI Desktop on their machine. Whereas Excel dashboards and reports have been used for decades and most people will know how to navigate Excel.

Answer (score 1):

Yes absolutely. Use Power Query to load the data from each individual file. Combine the queries and load the result into the Excel Data Model (aka Power Pivot). The Data Model can hold a lot more than 1 million worksheet rows. The limits are more related to the computer's memory capacity.

You can then easily build pivot tables from the data model.

That is what modern Excel with Power Pivot is all about.